# Exchange objects between Activity and Service

Tags: android, android-activity, service, exchange-server

I have an Activity "A" which instantiates two objects from the Facebook Android SDK. I put these two objects into a static HashMap with unique static keys and their references. From other activities "B" and "C" I'm able to get these two corresponding references via `myhashmap.get()`. These two Activities are within the same application. So far so good.

Within Activity "A" I start a Service also part of the same application. My problem is that I now want to get access to my two objects stored in the static HashMap of Activity "A" but the HashMap is empty?!?

So my question how can I get access to objects which were created by my Activity "A" from my service ?

Any tips are more than welcome

Answer (score 1):

> I put these two objects into a static HashMap with unique static keys and their references.

That is not a recommended technique in Java.

> Within Activity "A" I start a Service
>   also part of the same application. My
>   problem is that I now want to get
>   access to my two objects stored in the
>   static HashMap of Activity "A" but the
>   HashMap is empty?!?

Remove the `android:process="remote"` attribute from your manifest, if it is there -- you do not need it, you really do not want it, and it would cause this phenomenon.

> So my question how can I get access to objects which were created by my Activity "A" from my service ?

Put the objects in the service in the first place, and have your activities get them from the service using the local binding pattern.